# Spring Boot - Hibernate Envers - Liquibase - @Audit aware <insert> statements possible?

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase, hibernate-envers

Our app historically populated our `config` table entries via liquibase `<insert>` or `<update>` statements.
This `config` table is a jpa entity and leverages hibernate-envers `@Audit` functionality.

There is a corresponding `config_audit` table as well.

In order to audit entries inserted/updated via liquibase I'm contemplating switching over to a `<customChange>` changeset. e.g.

```
    <changeSet id="my_id" author="author">
        <customChange class="com.app.MyCustomTaskChange">
            <param name="field1" value="val1" />
            <param name="field2" value="val2" />
        </customChange>
    </changeSet>
```

```
public class MyCustomTaskChange implements CustomTaskChange, CustomTaskRollback {
    @Setter
    private String field1;

    @Setter
    private String field2;

    @Setter
    private static ConfigJpaRepository configJpaRepository;

    @Override
    public void execute(Database database) throws CustomChangeException {
        configJpaRepository.save(new ConfigEntity(field1, field2));
    }
    
    //other methods excluded for clarity
```

To be clear, the above approach works fine, entries are added both to `config` and `config_audit` tables as expected; however, I was wondering if there is a more elegant and future proof way of allowing the liquibase `<insert>` or `<update>` (or similar) statements to latch into the @Audit capabilities?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would recommend to stay clear of the idea using `spring` or `hibernate` in DB migrations, it complicates a lot of things regardless it's attractiveness, the main problem there is such migrations become outdated as soon as you modify domain model, and so, sooner or later `hibernate` may fail to write data into DB. In your case you somehow were able to "inject" repository instance into `CustomTaskChange` class just because `spring` initialised entity manager and repositories before running liquibase migrations, however in recent `spring` versions `spring-data-jpa` team introduced strong dependency between `liquibase` and `hibernate` and such approach should not work, however that is possible to do something like (sorry, can't recall how to enable `envers`):

```java
public class HibernateCustomTaskChange implements CustomTaskChange {

    @Override
    public void execute(Database database) throws CustomChangeException {
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = null;
        EntityManager entityManager = null;
        try {
            entityManagerFactory = getEntityManagerFactory(database, MyEntity.class);
            entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

            // some logic here


        } finally {
            if (entityManager != null) {
                entityManager.close();
            }
            if (entityManagerFactory != null) {
                entityManagerFactory.close();
            }
        }
    }


    protected EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory(Database database, Class<?>... entityClasses) {
        DataSource dataSource = createDataSource(database);
        ClassLoader classLoader = Scope.getCurrentScope().getClassLoader();
        MutablePersistenceUnitInfo pui = new MutablePersistenceUnitInfo() {
            @Override
            public ClassLoader getNewTempClassLoader() {
                return classLoader;
            }
        };
        pui.setNonJtaDataSource(dataSource);
        for (Class<?> entityClass : entityClasses) {
            pui.addManagedClassName(entityClass.getName());
        }
        Map<String, Object> settings = new HashMap<>();
        settings.put(AvailableSettings.CONNECTION_PROVIDER_DISABLES_AUTOCOMMIT, true);
        pui.setPersistenceUnitName("liquibase");
        return new EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl(
                new PersistenceUnitInfoDescriptor(pui),
                settings,
                classLoader
        ).build();
    }

    protected DataSource createDataSource(Database database) {
        Connection connection = ((JdbcConnection) database.getConnection()).getUnderlyingConnection();
        connection = createConnectionProxy(connection);
        return new SingleConnectionDataSource(connection, true);
    }

    protected Connection createConnectionProxy(Connection con) {
        return (Connection) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                ConnectionProxy.class.getClassLoader(),
                new Class<?>[]{ConnectionProxy.class},
                new CommitSuppressInvocationHandler(con));
    }

    static class CommitSuppressInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {

        private final Connection target;

        public CommitSuppressInvocationHandler(Connection target) {
            this.target = target;
        }

        @Override
        @Nullable
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            if (ReflectionUtils.isEqualsMethod(method)) {
                return (proxy == args[0]);
            } else if (ReflectionUtils.isHashCodeMethod(method)) {
                return System.identityHashCode(proxy);
            } else if (method.getName().equals("unwrap")) {
                if (((Class<?>) args[0]).isInstance(proxy)) {
                    return proxy;
                }
            } else if (method.getName().equals("isWrapperFor")) {
                if (((Class<?>) args[0]).isInstance(proxy)) {
                    return true;
                }
            } else if (method.getName().equals("close")) {
                return null;
            } else if (method.getName().equals("commit")) {
                return null;
            } else if (method.getName().equals("isClosed")) {
                return false;
            } else if (method.getName().equals("getTargetConnection")) {
                return this.target;
            }

            try {
                return method.invoke(this.target, args);
            } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                throw ex.getTargetException();
            }
        }

    }

    // some liquibase method omitted

}
```

Comment: Good point regarding migrations possibly becoming outdated.  
After all, in a new environment where Liquibase initially runs, the schema would safely evolve with ChangeSets, but the entity class would be 'fixed' at its latest version(possibly incompatible with early ChangeSets)  
Although I don't *think* the table for my use case will change, but I won't move forward with my approach as the risk of emulation by others without understanding the pitfalls is too high.

Comment: yep, you got a point, on the other hand you may always create a set of dummy entity classes and use them in particular change set only.