In a liquibase custom change, how can I construct a JPA EntityManager with access to the database?
In my Liquibase custom change (see https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/custom-change.html), I want to use JPA to modify some data.
In the implementation of CustomTaskChange.execute, I can access the JDBC connection via the passed Liquibase Database object (example code in Kotlin).
class MyCustomChange : CustomTaskChange {
    override fun execute(p0: Database?) {
        requireNotNull(p0)
        val liquibaseConnection = p0.connection as JdbcConnection
        val jdbcConnection = liquibaseConnection.wrappedConnection
        check(jdbcConnection != null)

        // ... with the JDBC connection, how can I create a EntityManager
        // bound to this connection?
        TODO("Create entity manager using the JDBC connection")

        // I have tried:
        val emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceunitname", mapOf("hibernate.dialect" to "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"))
        val em = emf.createEntityManager()
        println(em.createTypedQuery<...>("...").resultList)
        // ... but this of course gives an exception
        // UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
    }

Question:

Given the information available in the CustomTaskChange.execute context, how can I construct a JPA EntityManager instance that can access the database the migration is run against?


you may find some recipe there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76224091/3426309, it is based on spring classes (MutablePersistenceUnitInfo and SingleConnectionDataSource), though.
